How do you call two maps $F$, $G$ such that $F=G\circ\tau$, with $\tau$ homeomorphism?
It's an easy question, but I can't find an answer on this site.
It is a well-established terminology to call (topologically) conjugate two maps $f$ and $g$ from a topological space $X$ to itself such that $g\circ \tau=\tau\circ f$, with $\tau:X\to X$ being a homeomorphism.
Consider instead two maps $F,G:X\to Y$, with $X,Y$ topological spaces, such that $F=G\circ\tau$, with $\tau:X\to X$ homeomorphism. Is there a well-established term to describe the relation between $F$ and $G$? (Edit) In particular I was wondering, would the use of the word "conjugate" be correct in this case, or is it misleading?

Conjugate would not be correct in this case.  I don't know of any standard terminology.  Casually one would say something like "$F$ and $G$ differ by a homeomorphism."

An alternative would be also a change of variables. Supposing that $\tau(x)=y$, then $F(x)=G(\tau(x))=G(y)$, i.e., $F$ is just $G$ expressed with another variable. Since $\tau$ is a homeomorphism, the reverse holds as well: $G$ is just $F$ with another variable.
